# KendoUI observables and click binding

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have an observable array of objects that generates links on my page. I believe that I need to use observables because these tabs will be dynamically created and removed.

```
var TabsModel = kendo.observable({
        activeTabs: [
            { name: "tab1", isActive: kendo.observable(false) },
            { name: "tab2", isActive: kendo.observable(false) }
        ],
        loadTab: function () {
            // set clicked tab isActive to true
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
```

So I generate html via a template and I want to be able to click the tabs and run actions. Simple enough.

But I also want to be able to modify the link's properties. So on click, `isActive` becomes `true`, among other things.

Is it possible to access the clicked tab and change properties?

[JSFiddle clarification here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu7Vm/4/)

Comment: You can absolutely do this, especially if you are creating a custom template bound to the observable. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/click

Answer (score 1):

No such binding of the widget's option is not possible. You cannot bind and change options like isActive through MVVM.

Comment: Okay. I'm used to KnockoutJS. I guess it 2-way binding doesn't work like it does in KO. I'll have to figure something else out (maybe just Javascript/jQuery it). Thank you.